# differentiating circuit voltage gain

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, gain

[image: Differentiating Op-Amp Circuit]

Hi! I came across this question in lab, and it's been several years since I last done analog circuits. The voltage gain here in this op-amp should be 0.707 (-3db cut-off), and it asks us to find the capacitance. The way I see it is

V_in/(1000 + 1/jwC) = -V_out/10000

And after performing some simple arithmetic, we will be able to find the capacitance. However, the answer that I'm getting is wrong, so could anyone please show me the workings of how this should be done.

Much thanks fellas!

Comment: Are you remembering tthat w=2*pi*f?

Comment: 1000 = |-j 1/ωC|  did you use a slide rule?

Comment: @BeB00 yes I did

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, no, sorry whats a slide rule?

Comment: A quick way of performing division without a calculator

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 could you please tell me more about how the slide rule applies, the solutions say that the capacitance should be 3.2 microfarads, and i'm not getting that on my calculator

Comment: @A.Garrod if you show us the steps in your calculation, we can show where you went wrong. We need to know the frequency

Comment: @BeB00 is the formula i'm using for voltage gain correct? the frequency is 50Hz

Comment: @A.Garrod  did you understand the vector geometry rule in my answer?

Comment: "However, the answer that I'm getting is wrong" - OK, I'll bite. What answer are you getting, and how are you getting it?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter here that 1/j=-j -meaning -ve phase shift , but it does matter that 1/|Zin|=1/√(1+1) = 1/√2= 1/ 1.414= 0.707

meaning \$A_V= - \dfrac{R_f}{\sqrt{(R_{in}+2πfC)}}= -5/√2 \$

**Don't forget your Vector Algebra**

[image]
 But if you do, You may find the above handy in future

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA9TVd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

f = 50 Hz and Xc = 1000 ohms so C = \$\dfrac{1}{2\pi\times  50\times 1000}\$ = 3.183 uF.

Comment: but if Xc=1k, isnt Rin=2k and gain=-5?

Comment: -5 at f >= 2 decades when Xc goes towards 0 but -3dB or 0.707 of -5 when R=|Xc|

Comment: are we assuming that the reactor of the capacitance is 1000 ohms? if so, why?

Comment: @BeB00 no, Rin isn't 2k it's 1000 - j1000 and gain is 7.071

Comment: @A.Garrod yes, that produces the 3 dB point in the spectrum of this high pass filter circuit.

Comment: Ah right, i was confused at ops mixing of absolute gain of 0.707 and -3db point